# Excel formula to calculate difference between a column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel sheet]

how to calculate difference between a column value and column value in previous row. This should be calculated for entire column.

Column G should represent difference between rows of column E.

E.g.

G3 = E3 - E2

G4 = E4 - E3

G5 = E5 - E4

G6 = E6 - E5

and so on for entire column.

Similarly column H should represent difference between rows of column F.

E.g.

H3 = F3 - F2

H4 = F4 - F3

and so on for entire column.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Because it looks to me like you understand what formula to use.

Comment: I have to write formula for each row in G and H column. Suppose if there are thousand rows, i have to write it thousand times. Is there any way to write it once and it should apply to entire column ?

Comment: yes this is very [basic Excel functionality](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fill-a-formula-down-into-adjacent-cells-041edfe2-05bc-40e6-b933-ef48c3f308c6), use the "fill handle" to drag a formula and apply to a range of cells.

Comment: It Worked, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the cell that has the formula you want to fill into adjacent cells.
2. Drag the fill handle [image: Fill handle] across the cells that you want to fill.